# comparing two objects by two properties

Tags: c#, object, compare, linq-to-objects

How to sort two objects in a list by using two properties one by ascending and the other by descending order. when linq is used it says i need to implement IComparer interface but not sure how to compare two objects by using two properties at once.

Say Person class by Name ascending and Age descending.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you need to decide which is your *primary* comparison. Only use the *secondary* comparison if the first one gives equality. For example:

```
public int Compare(Person p1, Person p2)
{
    int primary = p1.Name.CompareTo(p2.Name);
    if (primary != 0)
    {
        return primary;
    }
    // Note reverse order of comparison to get descending
    return p2.Age.CompareTo(p1.Age);
}
```

(This can be written more compactly in various ways, but I've kept it very explicit so you can understand the concepts.)

Note that in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) I have some building blocks so you can easily construct comparers using lambda expressions, compose comparers etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a new copy of the list (so you still have the original order in your original list), you can do this:

```
List<Person> unsortedList;

sortedList = unsortedList.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ThenByDescending(p => p.Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this "[Implementing IComparer for Sorting Custom Objects](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2005/03/06/56584.aspx)"